# Print Estimator Name in SkLearn

Tags: python, model, scikit-learn

In Sklearn, is there a way to print out an estimator's class name?

I have tried to use the **name** attribute but that is not working.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression  

def print_estimator_name(estimator):
    print(estimator.__name__)

#Expected Outcome:
print_estimator_name(LogisticRegression())
```

I would expect this to print out the classifier name as above

Comment: `type(estimator)`?

Comment: What do you mean by name? Do you mean the class name? In which case type() should do the trick. Do you mean the memory address that is assigned to the instantiated object? Also maybe you just want the __str__() method on the object?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you are looking for `estimator.__class__.__name__` i.e.:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def print_estimator_name(estimator):
    print(estimator.__class__.__name__)

#Expected Outcome:
print_estimator_name(LogisticRegression())
```

Answer (score 4):

I have an alternative method. Get the object name, convert to str, get foremost child class with `split(".")`, and finally strip off unwanted chars

```
str(type(clf)).split(".")[-1][:-2]
```

This work for me in SKLearn, XGBoost, and LightGBM

```
print(f'Acc: {pred:0.5f} for the {str(type(clf)).split(".")[-1][:-2])}')
```

> ```
> Acc: 0.7159443 : DecisionTreeClassifier
> Acc: 0.7572368 : RandomForestClassifier
> Acc: 0.7548593 : ExtraTreesClassifier
> Acc: 0.7416970 : XGBClassifier
> Acc: 0.7582540 : LGBMClassifier
> ```